# Why hyphens property does not work in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, hyphenation

To adapt usability of the platfrom for mobile devices, I need ti utilize the css property hyphens. However, this property seems not to work in Chrome. Am I doing something wrong or are there any other solutions how to overcome it?

```
.title {
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto; }
```

This works pretty fine in Firefox and Safari, but not in Chrome. Any help?

Comment: Do you have a `lang` attribute on your `html` tag? This is mandatory for hyphens. Also, according to https://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens Chrome currently only supports hyphenation on Android and Mac.

Comment: Yes, lang="en" in html tag. Works perfectly in firefox and safari

Answer (score 1):

Hyphenation is currently supported for Chrome only on Android devices and macOS which is why you might be having this issue.

Further Reference: http://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens